# Queries from different databases (birt report)

Tags: sql, database, birt

So I have to execute something like this from a database we call "DB1":

```
select
app.START_DATE, app.LOCATION
from  appointment app
and app.USER_OID in ?
order by app.START_DATE
```

The app.USER_OID parameter is retrieved from another query executed on "DB2" so it's a different data set.

I can't order by date, because my output is in the following format:

```
OID1 - DATE1
OID1 - DATE4
OID1 - DATE5
OID2 - DATE2
OID2 - DATE3
```

but my output should be:

```
OID1 - DATE1
OID2 - DATE2
OID2 - DATE3
OID1 - DATE4
OID1 - DATE5
```

If I run the query from "DB1" like that:

```
select
app.START_DATE, app.LOCATION
from  appointment app
and app.USER_OID in (1,2)
order by app.START_DATE
```

it works perfectly.

I'm using Eclipse report design, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> I can't order by date, because my output is in the following format:

**Yes, you can order that by date** (*which is not really a* `DATE` *but is an integer within a string*). See below :

```
SELECT       ColumnName 
FROM         TableName
ORDER BY     SUBSTRING(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName), 2)
```

**Note that all you are doing here is extracting the integer value within the string and ordering the result set based on this integer.**

You can see this working here -> http://rextester.com/LAJ67839

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, sorry, the date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`, and the sorting is fine, the problem is that I can't use the rows retrieved from `query2` into the `IN` condition in `query1`. I can only use them with a `=` condition but doing this the result is that I have the oids ordered first, and the dates second, while it should be the other way